# Mobx computedFn not memorizing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, memory-management, mobx

In my React code, I am using and calling computedFn in multiple places. However, when I do console.log or debug step by step, I don't see it's memorizing anything, instead, it would execute the logic inside computedFn every time I call it.

Here is the code example in a .ts file:

```
const getComp = computedFn((num: number) => {
    console.log('**** get computed num');
    return num * num;
});

function testComputedFn() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getComp(8);
    }
}
```

And I can see that '**** get computed num' 10 times in console. So it seems like the memorization is not working at all? Not sure if I missed anything?

Here is a similar code where it can be test: https://playcode.io/1447230

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobx `computed`'s only memoize stuff inside reactive context, e.g. inside of `observer`, `reaction` and etc. Otherwise computed expressions are evaluated each time their value is requested, so they behave just like a normal property/method (no caching).

So to fix your example you just need to wrap `App` component with `observer` HOC.

```
import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

export const App = observer(...)
```

[More info in the docs](https://mobx.js.org/computeds.html#tips)